# Checking disk space on cordova iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova

I am trying to check disk space available in mobile using below code:

```
cordova.exec(function(result) {
    var diskSizeInMB = result/1024;
    alert(diskSizeInMB)
}, function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error);
}, "File", "getFreeDiskSpace", []);
```

In Android device it gives me correct result, whereas if I use iPhone/iPad it always returns me 0 as a output. Can anyone guide me how to resolve this issue? Or is there a way to check the disk size in iOS using cordova without writing custom plugin? To make this happen I haven't changed any configuration changes

Comment: might be a bug, I'll check and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9331), but was fixed long time ago.

Old answer:

I confirm there is a bug on the code, the problem is `getFreeDiskSpace` is undocumented and cordova team want to remove the native code as `getFreeDiskSpace` isn't part of the w3c file API.

If you want to fix the bug for you app, go to `CDVFile.m` and change the line

```
NSNumber* pNumAvail = [self checkFreeDiskSpace:self.appDocsPath];
```

to

```
NSNumber* pNumAvail = [self checkFreeDiskSpace:self.rootDocsPath];
```

on the `getFreeDiskSpace` method

Comment: Thank you I will check on this :)